# Sort date from string without using any of "Date" functions from jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I sort by date from string **without using any of jQuery "Date" functions or methods?**

Lets say that I have something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="article"><a href="#" class="">15/02/1966</a></li>
    <li class="article"><a href="#" class="">17/07/2003</a></li>
    <li class="article"><a href="#" class="">11/12/2007</a></li>
    <li class="article"><a href="#" class="">04/07/1951</a></li>
</ul>
```

How to sort them from lowest to biggest? Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you want to use them?

Comment: Why would you not use `Date()` functions? I suppose you use a pair of pliers to knock a nail into a piece of wood too.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but do Date functions work on dates before 1970 in jQuery?

Comment: @Matas: [The Date function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) has nothing to do with jQuery, it is pure JavaScript. And yes, your 1951 date for example would be converted to the timestamp `-591328800000` - sorting just works with them, too

Comment: @Bergi ... which is not bad :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You still could use alphabetical comparison, you only would need to reverse the dates into `YYYYMMDD`:

```
$ul = $("ul"); // or whatever selector you used
$ul.children().sort(function(a, b) {
    var ta = $(a).text().split("/").reverse().join();
    var tb = $(b).text().split("/").reverse().join();
    return (ta>tb) - (tb>ta);
}).appendTo($ul);
```

Comment: IMO, this solution is great. Can't get the reason for downvoting. Check the **DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/uqGUy/.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="article"><a href="#" class="">04/07/1951</a></li>
    <li class="article"><a href="#" class="">15/02/1966</a></li>
    <li class="article"><a href="#" class="">17/07/2003</a></li>
    <li class="article"><a href="#" class="">11/12/2007</a></li>
</ul>
```

BONUS: Didn't even have to use vanilla JS

Comment: http://cdn.memegenerator.net/instances/400x/21312572.jpg